# eigenvalues of $i\frac{d}{dx}$

Tags: operator-theory, laplacian

\begin{array}{l}
B:{\mathcal{D}}(B)\subset
L^2\big(]-a,a[\big)\longrightarrow
L^2\big(]-a,a[\big)\\\\
\displaystyle{\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad~~~~~~\varphi
\longrightarrow B\varphi(x)=i\frac{d\varphi}{dx}}\\\\
{\mathcal{D}}(B)=\left\{\varphi\in L^2\big(]-a,a[\big)\hbox{such
that} \displaystyle
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lambda_n\vert\langle\varphi,\varphi_n\rangle\vert^2<\infty\right\}
\end{array}
Can we say if the eigenvalues of $-
\displaystyle{\frac{d^2 }{dx^2}}$ are $\mu_n$, then the eigenvalues of $B$ are $\lambda_n=\sqrt{\mu_n}$?

Comment: You should perhaps add a bit more context if you want detailed answers. I gather you look at self-adjoint versions of the Laplacian and $B$ but which ones (if it can be described). The squareroot of $-\Delta$ has the mentioned eigen-values but doesn't quite look like $B$

Comment: what's the square root of $-\Delta$? isn't $B$?

Comment: Well for the standard Laplacian, $-\Delta \sin(\pi x/a) = (\pi /a)^2 \sin(\pi x/a)$ (an eigenvector) so its positive square-root $S=\sqrt{-\Delta}$ must verify: $S \sin(\pi x/a) = (\pi /a) \sin(\pi x/a)$ which is not the same as $B \sin (\pi x/a) = i (\pi/a) \cos(\pi x/a)$. As far as I recall, $S$ is non-local, i.e.  if $f$ is a smooth function with small compact support, then $Sf$ may have  support in the whole interval.

Answer (score 1):

If $\mu_n$ are the eigenvalues of B, then $B\varphi = \lambda \varphi $. So 
$$-\frac{\partial^2\varphi}{\partial x^2}=B^2 \varphi = i\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(i \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x}) = i\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\lambda \varphi)= \lambda^2 \varphi$$

So $\lambda^2 = \mu$ is true. Please note that you have only included the positive square root in your expression.

$\mu_n = \pm \sqrt{\lambda_n}$